# content-type wasn send by setting it with header() in php

Tags: php, http, header, response, content-type

I have a problem with setting the content-type by the php function header();
My complete code doesn't ever send any output. Only the response-object does it. Before every output i send the headers. Depending on the Accept-Header i set a Content-Type and do the right output, it in an easy way it looks like that:

```
switch($aceptHeader){ 
  case 'text/html': 
  #and some othe stupid acept-headers of the ie
    $this->setHeader('Content-Type: text/html; charset=".."');
    $this->sendHeaders();
    $this->sendDefault();
    break;
  case 'application/json':
    $this->setHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->sendJSON();
    break;  
  case 'application/xml':
    $this->setHeader('Content-Type: application/xml');
    $this->sendXML();
    break;
}
```

the method for the setHeader fills only an array, wicht will be put by an foreach-loop into the header(); function. This is not important, cause i tried it in the direct way by changing it `$this->setHeader()` to `header('Content-Type..');` it has got the same result (later)
The output ist just an rendering of an array by an twig template. This is the only output. The setting of the headers is not the problem. I even get a positive result, when i do a `print_r(header_list());`. There i see exactly that header i set before.
I see the same response header in almost every browser, but not in every:
the ie8 shows me only the html-code as a string in the body after a pre-tag. This was the reason, why i tested my page by the w3c validator (and other tools). All showed the same result:

**they get no Content-Type header**

what could be my mistake? Could there be any mistake before i set the header? 
- id do no wild inlcude stuff or anything else - the setting of the header make no trouble
- the only headers i change in the models between request and response is the http status, wich is followed by an `$response-send();` in almost every time.

Could there be a manipulation of the header while rendering the twig-template?

The Question is: What could disturb the setting of the content-type header by the header() function?

An interesting thing ist:
i put following code to the begining of my index.php

```
header('Content-Type: text/html');
echo 'test';
exit;
```

and than i get green test by all validation tool. The header was send.

I could go throught my whole code and look where i loose the header, but this could be a long long way. Is there anybody that has had the same problem or could imagine what i have done wrong?

This is only an look-a-like example. The switch block is not the problem, the sendHeader not, too. Cause i replaced them in different cases the whole afternoon by setting the header directly - every time with the same result.

I used these output switch for different cases and it works fine every time. I send json, with an header that $.ajax() of jQuery accepts as an json and not as an string. I produced xml for my RESTful api, that works fine and sends the data in that format i wanted it. Only the validator tool and the ie8 doesn't like it. And I don't understand why...

Comment: You need to put a `break` at the end of each of your cases or else all cases after the first one that matches will run regardless if the later cases match. Also, what is in the `setHeader` method? And is there a reason you call `sendHeaders` in the first case but not the others?

Comment: Another thing to check should `switch($aceptHeader)` actually read `switch($acceptHeader)`?

Comment: sorry for that orthographic chaos, wanted to write some code in the evening, without having the original one (at work).

Comment: @JonathanKuhn there is no reason. Think there is more code smell than this example. I should write special classes for each send-method instead of these methods, that i call in there, wich sometimes call the `$this->sendHeaders();` on their own and sometimes not. But this is a question of refactoring of code. I could replace the whole switch block by `header('content-type:..'); echo ''; exit;` and nothing would change (i tried these cases the whole afternoon). 
The switch is not the problem, the method to set the header isn`t the problem, the output isn`t hopefully not the problem.

Comment: Well if just sending the header with `header()` works, try creating the most basic page possible that includes the class and calls `setHeader`. If you get the header, then the method is fine. If you don't, something is wrong with the method. Without being able to see the source of `setHeader` and `sendHeaders`, no one would be able to tell what the problem is because those methods set/send the actual headers. Other than the few mistakes we told you about, there is nothing wrong with the code shown.

Comment: It does NOT work with an direkt Setting of the header with header(). Even that is my problem, and that is the Thing i wanna explain undepended from my implementation if i try to set the content-type at this Point of the Script, it does Not work. Sample code should only show how i implement the question of setting it normaly. I am at work in two hours and post real code. But what would be better edit than edit the First post?

Answer (score 0):

```
switch($aceptHeader){ 
  case 'text/html': 
  #and some othe stupid acept-headers of the ie
    $this->setHeader('Content-Type: text/html; charset=".."');
    $this->sendHeaders();
    $this->sendDefault();
    break;
  case 'application/json':
    $this->setHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->sendJSON();
    break;
  case 'application/xml':
    $this->setHeader('Content-Type: application/xml');
    $this->sendXML();
    break;
}
```

Forgot the breaks in which tell the code when to try the next case.

Comment: I would move the `text/html` to the bottom and use `default` - `case 'text/html': default:`

Comment: sorry only forgot them here in the example, will paste the org. code tomorrow in the morning when i am back at work.

Comment: yes in real code the is an extra default part like wich is equal to the first case (for all unknown accept headers)

Comment: the w3c validator says: Non-XML Content-Type: .

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Problem.

And...

it was a problem of the implementation. It was a thing you can't see, cause i don't post it.
Indeed it was the default path, where i send that wath the client wants to get as Content-Type. Mean if the client (IE8 or validation tools) sends no accept-header or an empty string i send and "Content-Type: " this is fail. I could cry. grrrrrrrrrr. Sorry for that.

To let you know my right implementation (needs some refactoring i know):

```
    $acceptFormat = $this->request->getAcceptFormat();
#do a switch for the type of the output and send the headers before
switch ($acceptFormat ){
  case 'text/html':
  case 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
  case 'application/x-ms-application':
  case 'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml':
  case '*/*':
    $this->setHeader('content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    $this->_sendHeaders();
    $this->_sendDefault();
    break;
  case 'application/json':
    $this->setHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->_sendHeaders();
    $this->_sendJSON();
    break;
  case 'application/xml':
    $this->setHeader('Content-Type: application/xml');
    $this->_sendHeaders();
    $this->_sendXML();
    break;
  default:
    $this->debugger->log('Unknown Accept-Header set: '.$acceptFormat.' for setting the Content-Type ');
    #$this->setHeader('content-type: '.$acceptFormat);
    $this->setHeader('content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    $this->_sendHeaders();
    $this->_sendDefault();
    break;
}
```

the commented part was the fault.

oh my god. ...

but i could never imagine, that a browser would ever send nothing as accept-type.